# Regex - repeating capture

Tags: c#, regex

I have a fragment like:

```
<meta property="size" content="38R|38L|44R|36R|44L|42R|42L|40S|40R|40L|38S" />
```

And I wish to return: `38R`, `38L`, `44R` ... as separate matches/captures

I'm a bit stuck - I've tried a billion things, but felt a repeating '+' guy may be the answer:

`<meta property="size" content="((.*?)\|)+`

Any help most appreciated.

The coide that extracts the values looks like this:

```
var values = match
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

I can't change it - and have to use a regex in this case.

This regex from Wiktor below did the trick!

```
 (?:<meta\s+property="size"\s+content="|(?!^)\G\|?)(\w+)
```

Comment: Can you just parse out the `content` attribute value with `XElement.Parse`? Then, you'd just split with `|`.

Comment: what does this have to do with c#?

Comment: People will tell you not to use regex for this, and that's because you might get funky stuff like `property="content=abcdefg" content="38R|....`

Comment: @SamIam It's using the C# Regex engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can get the values without a regex. Add a `System.Xml.Linq` namespace and you can parse the contents of the string like this:

```
var input = "<meta property=\"size\" content=\"38R|38L|44R|36R|44L|42R|42L|40S|40R|40L|38S\" />";
var xml = XElement.Parse(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", input));
var content = xml.Elements("meta")
        .Select(c => c.Attribute("content").Value).FirstOrDefault();
var res = content.Split('|');
```

[image]

If - by any chance - that solution is not working for you, a fallback regex solution can be

```
var input = "<meta property=\"size\" content=\"38R|38L|44R|36R|44L|42R|42L|40S|40R|40L|38S\" />";
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?:<meta\s+property=""size""\s+content=""|(?!^)\G\|?)(\w+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/GkdYOv)

Note that the `\w+` (1 or more word chars) can be replaced with your `[^|"]+`.

Comment: I have to use a Rexex sadly, its an input to the system i'm working on

Comment: Does that mean you have no access to the *CaptureCollection*? Do you need to access the `|`-separated strings as separate matches? Try [`(?:<meta\s+property="size"\s+content="|(?!^)\G\|?)(\w+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%3cmeta%5cs%2bproperty%3d%22size%22%5cs%2bcontent%3d%22%7c(%3f!%5e)%5cG%5c%7c%3f)(%5cw%2b)&i=%3cmeta+property%3d%22size%22+content%3d%2238R%7c38L%7c44R%7c36R%7c44L%7c42R%7c42L%7c40S%7c40R%7c40L%7c38S%22+%2f%3e). See http://ideone.com/GkdYOv.

Comment: Nope :(

This is the code that gets the matches

var values = match
 .Cast<Match>()
 .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
 .ToList();